# Dual boot two instances ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, 14.04

I want to dual boot two instances of ubuntu server 14.04. I want to do this that way I can work on a website for my school, as well as have a space for me to develop that is completely sandboxed from one another and both hosted on port 80. (I do not need them running at the same time) Based on the research that I have done, I believe that this is the only way to do this, but if you have any other suggestions, I would be glad to hear it. I am not sure how to dual boot in the installation of the server because I am not used to how it looks. Do I have to partition it in the first installation or the second? How do I partition it? Are there any videos that I should refer to that might be able to guide me through it?

Comment: Have you thought about installing both instances as VM's, that way they can both run at the same time and you can scale their specs (RAM, Disk Space, CPU's) as needs change in the future.

Comment: Well, I want to run it on one of my old computers upstairs. It does have enough memory to run one operating system, but it does not have enough memory or a fast enough processor to run both. Plus, I do not them running at the same time, since I want them both to forward to port 80

Comment: Thanks for the updated information, in this case dual booting should be very easy -- I will write an answer for you.

Comment: @levlaz thank you very much. I am glad to help clarify information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information about dual booting in general check out this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot).

For your specific case, this is what I would do. (Let's Assume you have 1 100GB Hard Drive and 4GB of RAM, you can adjust the amount of space based on your specific situation)

1) Boot Ubuntu Server 14.04 and [change the partition table](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/) to look something like this.

- Partition 1: ext4 50 GB Mounted on / (We will use this for the school instance)
- Partition 2: ext4 45 GB Mounted on / (We will use this for the home instance)
- Partition 3: swap 5 GB (This will be shared swap area for both instances)

2) Now run the installer and choose the first partition for your school website.

3) Reboot and run the installer again, this time choosing the second partition for your personal sandbox website.

4) Reboot again, and you should see both options in GRUB, select the one that you want to use and you should be good to go.

Comment: One more question, can I default to one?

Comment: @matthapkidokarate I just inserted an extra link on advanced partitioning in case you get stuck. By default I believe GRUB will just boot to the first selected partition (which is the first one that you make on the physical hard drive)

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that as soon as I posted the comment.

Comment: Awesome, this should be pretty straightforward, let us know if you get stuck. Good luck! :)

Comment: one question though . . . Is a partition mounted on /home required for server?

Comment: If you mount the partition to just / it will place your home (and all other partitions) in there for you. A separate /home partition is only necessary if you want separate your documents, files, pictures, music, etc.. from the rest of the OS. Check out this link for a good overview of the basic linux directory structure. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJJK1iZHTSfVlpQQklRZUNyTHM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have you Considered using LXC Containers? ( https://linuxcontainers.org/ )

This will avoid you having to partition your server all togehter.

Containers are simliar virtualization, but each container is like its own OS however it shares the kernel of the parent OS but is an otherwise an completely sandboxed environment. It's really easy to create a container and start it.

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n p1
lxc-start -n p1 -d
```

Once that is setup, you can ssh into that container and do your development work.

To list your containers run this command:

```
lxc-ls --fancy p1
```

We use containers at work to sandbox our web applications so that we can host several applications on a single server with out any overlap in each container's configuration. each of our containers has its own ip so we can forward any traffic to specific container if it needs to be public facing.

Comment: You can also have multiple containers running at the same time.

Comment: I will try the previous answer first since I am already in progress with it. Then I'll try your way if the previous way does not work